# Livereload not working when i edit component Angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

i'm trying to use Angular-cli in v1.0.0 beta.30, but when i run my project with `ng serve` live reload works only on html's files and not on ts's files.

- is it a normal behavior on angular-cli that i have to rebuild my project to see changes on my components?

i made angular2 quickstart from official site before and when i edited a component and could see changes on real time.

Comment: What does your browser console say? @Jonathan

Comment: are you wroking with webstorm?

Comment: Not an answer, probably not super helpful. But I have also seen this happen on occasion with `"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.26",`. Using Intellij.

Comment: @BradAxe it says `[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?93b6:38 [WDS] Nothing changed.` but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @YoavSchniederman i'm using Visual studio code

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ShPoJ this is a screenshot of my shell, chrome app and  code